# Nuxt 3 async composable

Tags: vue.js, async-await, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm having the following async composable in Nuxt 3 and it doesn't work as expected, coming from a React background I think I am missing something.

I have the following code in my composable.

```js
// useAsyncFoo.js
export default () => {
  const foo = ref(null);

  someAsyncFn().then(value => foo.value = value);

  return foo;
}
```

Then on my page, I use it like this:

```html
<script setup>
const foo = useAsyncFoo();

console.log(foo); // null
</script>

...
```

I expect that `foo` to take the value of the value returned by the promise but it's always `null`.

It is common to await composables in Nuxt 3? (`await useAsyncFoo()`) and export it as an async function? I am doing something wrong?

Comment: If you want to use `await` here, you should probably write your whole composable as `async/await`. Do you see the call in your network tab? Also, I guess that you typo'd in your second snippet (`useFoo`? or rather `useAsyncFoo`?)

Comment: @kissu, you are right, updated. It is common to await composables? And yes, I see the request.

Comment: Yeah, totally common use-case of course.

Comment: Try to refacto your composable into using async/await and call `const foo = await useAsyncFoo()` before your console. Should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, as a react dev it feels like I am doing something wrong await hooks but I guess that's the confusion.

Comment: @kissu any idea why HMR throws this error when I'm awaiting the composable? ```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_leaveCb')```

Comment: You should wrap your async call inside a function and returns it from your composable like this: `const bar = async ()=>{ foo.value = await someAsyncFn() }; return {foo, bar}`. So whenever you want to update the `foo` variable, you just need to call `bar()`

Answer (score 0):

I spent an afternoon trying to transfer data from a composable to a page but I always ended up with weird or undefined data. Reading the comments here I finally understood what I was missing and managed to do it, so thanks! If it can helps, here are my files.

(FetchWrapper is a composable I made inspired by this [article](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/05/26/vue-3-pinia-jwt-authentication-tutorial-example) so I don't have to add token on each request, but it uses the Nuxt $fetch method.)

My composable

```js
export const useFoo = () => {
  const { fetchWrapper } = useFetchWrapper()
  const bar = ref([])

  const getApiData = async () => {
    try {
      bar.value = await fetchWrapper
        .get(`${useRuntimeConfig().public.API_URL}/foobar`, null)
    } catch(error) {
      //
    }
  }

  return { bar, getApiData }
}
```

My page

```html
<script setup>
  const { bar, getApiData } = useFoo()
  await getApiData()
</script>

<template>
  {{ bar }}
</template>
```

Comment: I'd also recommend using the `async/await` syntax everywhere rather than `.then` too.

Comment: Hi @kissu thanks for your insight. I'd be happy to know why you think it's better and maybe an example?

Comment: Mainly to avoid "callback hell" and have something more tidy. As of how to write it, you can check the explanation/examples here: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: If I got this right, I should do `bar.value = await fetchWrapper.get...` instead of assigning the value in a `then()`? And wrap it with a `try/catch` for errors?

Comment: Yes, this is the way. Will look cleaner overall!

Comment: Thanks a lot @kissu, I edited my message, hope I did it right. And I'll definitely update my code as well. Love to improve my coding :)

Comment: Yep, looks great! You're welcome. Keep improving! :)